# mypy "has incompatible type" error with abc abstract interface

Tags: python, mypy

here is a snippet of my code

```
# define custom types
PersonDetails = TypeVar("PersonDetails", bound="PersonDetailsAbstractInterface", covariant=True)
```

the typevar is bound to the abc abstract interface and is set to be covariant

here is the implementation of the abstract interface

```
@dataclass
class PersonDetailsAbstractInterface(ABC, PersonDetailsBase):
    """Person Personal Details Abstract Interface"""
```

I then have 4 actual implementations of the class called:

- PersonalInfo
- Employment
- UpdateStatus
- Vehicle

here below another class which makes up all the other PersonDetail classes and the from_iterables classmethod takes iterables of the above 4 classes and construct the final Person class.

```
@dataclass
class Person(Generic[PersonDetails]):
    personal_info: PersonalInfo
    employment: Employment
    update_status: UpdateStatus
    vehicle: Vehicle

    @classmethod
    def from_iterables(cls, *iterables: Iterable[PersonDetails]) -> Generator[Person, None, None]:
        iterators = [iter(iterable) for iterable in iterables]

        while True:
            try:
                construction_values = [next(iterator) for iterator in iterators]
                yield Person(*construction_values)

            except StopIteration:
                break
```

the code works but when I run mypy here is the error it returns.

```
error: Argument 1 to "Person" has incompatible type "*list[PersonDetails]"; expected "PersonalInfo"  [arg-type]
error: Argument 1 to "Person" has incompatible type "*list[PersonDetails]"; expected "Employment"  [arg-type]
error: Argument 1 to "Person" has incompatible type "*list[PersonDetails]"; expected "UpdateStatus"  [arg-type]
error: Argument 1 to "Person" has incompatible type "*list[PersonDetails]"; expected "Vehicle"  [arg-type]
```

the problem seems to be the clasmethod `from_iterables(cls, *iterables: Iterable[PersonDetails])`
However, `PersonDetails` is bound to the abstract interface, which all the 4 classes inherit from, and additionally, `PersonDetails` is also set as `covariant`.

Any idea as to why mypy is complaining?

EDIT:
here is how i call it.
it works well at runtime

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    personal_info_data = PersonalInfo.from_file("personal_info.csv")
    employment_data = Employment.from_file("employment.csv")
    update_status_data = UpdateStatus.from_file("update_status.csv")
    vehicles_data = Vehicle.from_file("vehicles.csv")

    person_data = Person.from_iterables(
        personal_info_data, employment_data, update_status_data, vehicles_data
    )
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how you're calling `from_iterables`?  I'm having trouble following the code, but I have a strong suspicion that if this works at runtime it's because it doesn't agree with your type annotations.

Comment: All `Employment` are `PersonalDetails`, but not all `PersonalDetails` are `Employment`. Also does the class need to be Generic? Couldn't you simply do: `PersonalDetails: TypeAlias = tuple[PersonalInfo, Employment, UpdateStatus, Vehicle]`? Also also, is there a reason you are not using `zip` but implementing `zip` yourself?

Comment: @SayandipDutta I have more in the Person class, I have just removed some of the code to clean it up and highlight the problem. when you say All Employment are PersonalDetails, but not all PersonalDetails are Employment. this seems to me like I should set my PersonDetails TypeVar to contravariant but even if I do so mypy returns the exact same error.

Comment: @Samwise, just added to the OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass an arbitrary `PersonDetails` as an arbitrary argument to the `Person` constructor; if you rearranged your caller so that it passed the different details in a different order, it would still conform to your `from_iterables` signature, but it would break `Person`.

`from_iterables` should typecheck correctly (and work with your existing calling code) if you indicate the expected type of each argument in a way that conforms to the signature of `Person`:

```
    @classmethod
    def from_iterables(
        cls,
        personal_infos: Iterable[PersonalInfo],
        employments: Iterable[Employment],
        update_statuses: Iterable[UpdateStatus],
        vehicles: Iterable[Vehicle],
    ) -> Iterator[Person]:
        return (
            Person(*construction_values)
            for construction_values in zip(
                personal_infos,
                employments,
                update_statuses,
                vehicles
            )
        )
```

If you wanted to be able to pass an arbitrary sequence of `PersonDetails` iterables to this function, then `Person` would need to be modified in such a way as to be constructible from an arbitrary sequence of `PersonDetails` instances.

Comment: thanks! I’ll adjust the signature of from_iter able. However, regardless of the fact that my signature would break the code if the order in the caller was changed, I still don’t understand why mypy was complaining on the old code when all the implementations are subtype of PersonDetails

Comment: Because that's not sufficient to satisfy the interface of `Person`.  Try rearranging the order of the `personal_infos`, `employments`, etc arguments in the code in my answer -- you should get a mypy error because now `Person` isn't getting the args in the expected order.  If you just type all the args as arbitrary `PersonDetails` instead of the *specific* `PersonDetails` types expected by `Person`, the same error is possible.  Mypy's job is to make that type of error impossible.

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation! I see the point! it does make sense.